# Why does NSPredicate accessibilityIdentifier fail?

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

When I run a test with the following code:

```
let shuffle = app.buttons.elementMatchingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "accessibilityIdentifier=%@", "shuffle"))
expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "hittable=TRUE"), evaluatedWithObject: shuffle, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(2) {_ in}
shuffle.tap()
```

The test fails.  But when I use this code:

```
let shuffle = app.buttons["shuffle"]
expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "hittable=TRUE"), evaluatedWithObject: shuffle, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(2) {_ in}
shuffle.tap()
```

http://www.bricepollock.com/difference-xcode-ui-testing-ui-automation-instrument/

This guy says specifically that a huge improvement to UIT over UIA is that UIT uses queries that are quickly evaluated every time it is used, instead of evaluating once and operating on the result set.  It seems there is a poor design principle here.  Can anyone explain what is wrong with the first query?

```
expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate("ANY accessibilityIdentifier=%@"), evaluatedWithObject: app.buttons)
```

Doesn't seem to work either.  Is there documentation that describes which functions are queries and which are result sets?  I could only find 1 page on Apple's site that describes how to use this new XCUI suite, and it is severely limited on examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend watching the WWDC video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/

Also, this place looks to have the documentation on the XCUI* objects you'll use in unit testing:
http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/

I don't have a specific answer for why something is failing because that lies in part on your UI. Looks like you are setting the accessibility identifier which looks correct. I would write this test like so:

```
let shuffle = app.buttons["shuffle"]
XCTAssert(shuffle.hittable == true)
shuffle.tap()
```

Timeouts aren't typically necessary anymore with the Xcode UI Testing framework.

Comment: WWDC link is dead. Your second link currently points to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest